# Compile ROS Comm without catkin_make_isolated

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Comm now depends on a non-catkin package, console_bridge.  This means catkin_make no longer works.  Unfortunately, I can't convince catkin to use my cross compile toolchain when using catkin_make_isolated, so I just end up with host-binaries.

I'm cross compiling ROS Comm Hydro for an i.MX53 Cortex A8 ARM board. I had configured yujin_tools (thanks Daniel) to cross-compile the ROS Comm sources before the console_bridge dependency existed.  Now, "yujin_make" (which calls catkin_make) no longer works.

How can I convince yujin and/or catkin to build ROS Comm with my xc toolchain?

```
~/ros_yws/digi  $ yujin_make
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/robonaut/ros_yws/digi/src -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/robonaut/ros_yws/digi/toolchain.cmake -C/home/robonaut/ros_yws/digi/config.cmake" in "/home/robonaut/ros_yws/digi/build"
####
loading initial cache file /home/robonaut/ros_yws/digi/config.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -- works
...snip...
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:88 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.
```

So yujin_make uses the toolchain correctly, but catkin doesn't like console_bridge.

```
~/ros_yws/digi  $ yujin_make_isolated
...snip...
==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/catkin'
==> cmake /home/robonaut/ros_yws/native/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/robonaut/ros_yws/native/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/robonaut/ros_yws/native/install_isolated in '/home/robonaut/ros_yws/native/build_isolated/catkin'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
...snip...
~/ros_yws/digi  $ file devel_isolated/console_bridge/lib/libconsole_bridge.so 
devel_isolated/console_bridge/lib/libconsole_bridge.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x6d0102a6e7bbb8584315b962cdb8c023aea2137f, not stripped
```

But yujin_make_isolated fails to use the toolchain, even though catkin is happy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121531/compile-ros-comm-without-catkin_make_isolated/) by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on 2014-01-23**:
If I convert console_bridge into a catkin package, things work swimmingly.  But I assume it's not a catkin package on purpose...  hm.

https://github.com/dustingooding/console_bridge-release/tree/feature/catkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The i.MX boards support Ubuntu well; would it be easier to use the ARM debs http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM ?

It looks like there are a number newer Ubuntu of builds for the i.MX53 linked off of the [i.MX53 Quickstart guide](http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/i.MX53+Quick+Start).

I would start with [one of the 13.04 builds](https://rcn-ee.net/deb/minfs/raring/) and start browsing the server from there.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on 2014-01-24**:
I've only been able to find 11.10 for i.MX.  I was hoping to find at least 12.04 (LTS and all).  Are you aware of a 12.04 build?